# Pandas Data Frame Subsetting

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame where the index are the dates.

```
>>>df

Date        Mean NDVI       STD     R²           Satellite
2018/05/07  0.139239    0.0324461   0.121766    Satellite B
2018/05/15  0.130177    0.0340713   0.0832709   Satellite B
2018/05/17  0.0852999   0.0667223   0.0344545   Satellite B
2018/05/30  0.0366202   0.0419196   0.0029048   Satellite B
2018/08/18  0.621853    0.0552849   0.560544    Satellite B
2018/09/04  0.51118     0.0636208   0.209225    Satellite B
2018/07/12  0.0284805   0.00935047  0.493559    Satellite C
2018/07/21  0.0438943   0.0158732   0.404927    Satellite C
2018/08/13  0.0418866   0.00945358  0.285964    Satellite C
2018/08/22  0.0427927   0.0124615   0.186457    Satellite C
2018/08/29  0.0396067   0.0131304   0.267189    Satellite C
2018/09/23  -0.0008     0.00986078  0.013689    Satellite C

>>>df2.index
Index(['2018/05/07', '2018/05/15', '2018/05/17', '2018/05/30', '2018/06/01',
   '2018/06/04', '2018/07/12', '2018/07/21', '2018/08/13',
   '2018/08/22', '2018/08/29', '2018/09/23'],
  dtype='object')
```

I need to plot the Mean NDVI of the all images collected from Satellite B (against date). To do that, I need to create a new dataframe where only the data of Satellite B will be there. Is there any way of subsetting them to the following dataframe?

```
>>>df2

Date        Mean NDVI       STD     R²           Satellite
2018/05/07  0.139239    0.0324461   0.121766    Satellite B
2018/05/15  0.130177    0.0340713   0.0832709   Satellite B
2018/05/17  0.0852999   0.0667223   0.0344545   Satellite B
2018/05/30  0.0366202   0.0419196   0.0029048   Satellite B
2018/08/18  0.621853    0.0552849   0.560544    Satellite B
2018/09/04  0.51118     0.0636208   0.209225    Satellite B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
df2 = df.loc[df['Satellite'] == 'Satellite B'].copy()
```